# form.$submitted not working on transcluded element

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have something like this:

```
<my-directive name="form"><div ng-if="form.$submitted"></div></my-directive>
```

and in my directive:

```
angular.directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
        template: '<form name="{{ name }}" ng-transclude></form>',
        transclude: true,
        scope: {
            name: '@'
        },
        link: function(scope) {
            console.log(scope.form.$submitted); //works here
        }
    }
});
```

`form.$submitted` doesn't seem to be defined here? But it is defined inside the scope of the directive? How can I access `form.$submitted` from HTML?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The transcluded (with `ng-transclude`) content has a different scope than the directive's isolate scope.

You *could* transclude manually and apply the isolate scope to the transcluded content:

```
template: '<form name="{{ name }}"></form>',
transclude: true,
scope: {
   name: "@"
},
link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrls, transcludeFn){
   transcludeFn(scope, function(contentClone){
     element.find("form").append(contentClone);
   });
}
```

but it is a bit awkward to the user of your directive, since now they have HTML that refers to some "magic" variables (which are of-course defined by your directive) that are not apparent to someone observing the HTML:

```
<my-directive name="form">
   <pre>{{form}}</pre>
</my-directive>
```

Here, it is not obvious what `{{form}}` refers to.